# Not able to launch Snapcraft and Skype in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: skype, snap, ubuntu-store

I installed Snapcraft and Skype using snap package in Ubuntu 18.04 using terminal. When I tried to launch snapcraft it is prompting `/var not root-owned 1000:0`.

[image]

Comment: What's the output of `ls -ld /var`?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 15 manish root 4096 Jan 28  2017 /var
this is the output of it.

Comment: Looks like you broke the ownership on /var I'm afraid.

Comment: I did not understand what you said